# Auth fail happennin :com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Auth fail

Tags: java, linux, unix, authentication, tcpclient

I have tried below code but i am keep getting exception as follow,
Please let me know what i am missing here.. Thanks in advance...

> com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Auth fail
>               at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:473)
>               at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:145)
>               at FileCopierOverNetwork.main(FileCopierOverNetwork.java:34)

sample program :

```
import com.jcraft.jsch.Channel;
import com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp;
import com.jcraft.jsch.JSch;
import com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException;
import com.jcraft.jsch.Session;
import com.jcraft.jsch.SftpException;

public class FileCopierOverNetwork
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        String hostname = "1010.15.15";
        String username = "xxxxxx";
      String password = "yyyyyy";
        String copyFrom = "/opt/jboss-eap-5.1/jboss-as/server/xxxdsd/test/";
        String copyTo = "/opt/jboss-eap-5.1/jboss-as/server/xccxcxc/java_programs/test1/"; 
        JSch jsch = new JSch();
        Session session = null;
        System.out.println("Trying to connect.....");
        try
        {
            session = jsch.getSession(username, hostname, 22);
            java.util.Properties config = new java.util.Properties(); 
            config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
            session.setConfig(config);


            //jsch.setKnownHosts("ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABIwAAAIEA5XGH3MBKc84gKuZNVMZYrXOhZZuio3+43wVqKs22ZHrJj82zLNO9TQGLSlH47hLy32g/BDvdVJAko1SH04p/PRpdXijTf5f4xCsL+Ke3pEkZstSBu4+XPTxUDz0kNqZREtqapHGjf7YxbkRRRUdfvM+h4LWujcNO5r+U2la89xU=");
            System.out.println("password before.....");

            session.setPassword(password);
            System.out.println("password after.....");
            session.connect(); 
            System.out.println("after connect.....");
            Channel channel = session.openChannel("sftp");
            ChannelSftp sftpChannel = (ChannelSftp) channel;
            channel.connect();
            sftpChannel.cd(".");
            sftpChannel.get(copyFrom, copyTo);
            sftpChannel.exit();
            session.disconnect();
        } catch (JSchException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();  
        } catch (SftpException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("Done !!");
    }
}
```